# Unable to execute selenium webdriver scripts in safari 5 Browser

Tags: selenium, safari

I have downloaded the Apple Developer certificate and also configured the Safari Extension in my framework. Now, when I start executing the script, the Browser is launched, it is performing few actions and then it is throwing the following error.

(Note: I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar)

> Mar 5, 2013 3:59:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
>       INFO: Server started on port 5674
>       Mar 5, 2013 3:59:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler$1 operationComplete
>       INFO: Connection opened
>       Mar 5, 2013 3:59:45 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler
>       WARNING: EXCEPTION, please implement org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler.exceptionCaught() for proper handling.
>       java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:59)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:465)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:332)
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Mar 5, 2013 3:59:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
>       INFO: Stopping server

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error after calling `safariDriver.quit()`. It turns out that SafariDriver didn't close the socket even though it knew that it was going to terminate. To fix the issue, I've adjusted the behavior of the `QUIT` command, and included the patch with my PR for another feature related to the Safari Driver: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/87.

The actual fix is quite straightforward, view it at https://github.com/Rob--W/selenium/commit/2b53d4b61.

Want to implement this fix yourself? Follow the following steps:

1. Install the pre-requisites (available for Linux, Mac and Windows):

   - Java Development Kit (JDK, not just the JRE)
   - Ruby
   - Git
2. Clone the Selenium repository:

   ```
   git clone https://code.google.com/p/selenium/
   ```
3. Apply [my commit](https://github.com/Rob--W/selenium/commit/2b53d4b61f26fb4c857932bf404a45a44fa4582c).
4. At the root of the Selenium repository, run the following command:

   ```
   ./go selenium-server-standalone offline=true
   ```

   (if you're using Windows, omit `./` :)

   ```
   go selenium-server-standalone offline=true
   ```
5. Wait a while. The initial build takes several minutes, subsequent builds are done within a minute. The desired result is found in the following directory (relative to the repository's root):

   ```
   build/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/selenium/selenium-standalone.jar
   ```